# Как определить, где нужно ставить тире и какое предложение содержит однотипно построенные части?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, члены-предложения

> Тире ставится в неполном предложении, составляющем часть сложного
>   предложения, когда пропущенный член (обычно сказуемое)
>   восстанавливается из предыдущей части фразы и в месте пропуска
>   делается пауза.
>
> При отсутствии паузы в месте пропуска члена предложения тире не
>   ставится.

А если я считаю, что в предложении пауза всё-таки есть, ведь пауза - это очень субъективная вещь. Разве вот это предложение нельзя произнести с паузой перед словом "Егорушку"?

> Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку.

При этом:

> Тире ставится в однотипно построенных частях сложного предложения при
>   пропуске какого-либо члена (иногда и без пропуска).

А разве предложение

> Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку

не содержит однотипно построенных частей сложного предложения? В обоих частях используется один и тот же глагол. Как понять, где однотипно построенные части, а где - нет? И разве первое правило с паузой не может как-бы перекрыть это правило?

Comment: Пожалуйста, это моя просьба, не  надо менять уже принятый ответ. У Александра очень хороший и правильный  текст, и его материал я использовала в своем ответе.  Два ответа всего лишь ответа дополняют друг друга, в них использованы разные методики, поэтому не хотелось бы видеть здесь конкуренции.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо за оценку. В Справке рекомендуется сразу не принимать ответ, а подождать хотя бы день-два, чтобы потом определить для себя наиболее полезный. Но вопрос и так оставался без ответа три дня. Мне кажется, человек вправе отправить галочку другому. (Вы можете просто проголосовать за мой ответ, что будет очень приятно.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Разве вот это предложение нельзя произнести с паузой перед словом "Егорушку"?
```

*Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку.*

Вы правы насчёт паузы, и вроде бы правило не запрещает ставить тире. Но каждый случай нужно рассматривать отдельно. Всё зависит от расставленных акцентов, от ритмики фраз и, конечно, от контекста, от взаимообусловленности частей предложения. В этом предложении два персонажа, которые *оглядывают* друг друга — занимаются одним и тем же. Особых ударений, пауз, внезапных перемен, противопоставлений не ощущается. Тире "не просится". Читается оно спокойно, с обычными интонационными ударениями:

*Егорушка долго оглядывал ег**О**, а он Ег**О**рушку.* Чтобы убедиться как выглядит и читается предложение в контексте, обратимся к источнику.

Вот отрывок из повести Чехова [«Степь. История одной поездки»](http://chehov-lit.ru/chehov/text/step/step-2.htm):

> С тупым удивлением и не без страха, точно видя перед собой выходцев с того света, он, не мигая и разинув рот, оглядывал кумачовую рубаху Егорушки и бричку.
>   Красный цвет рубахи манил и ласкал его, а бричка и спавшие под ней люди возбуждали его любопытство; быть может, он и сам не заметил, как приятный красный цвет и любопытство притянули его из поселка вниз, и, вероятно, теперь удивлялся своей смелости. **Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку.** Оба молчали и чувствовали некоторую неловкость. После долгого молчания Егорушка спросил:
>
> — Тебя как звать?

Предположим, что в предложении появляется что-то третье:

*Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он — бричку.* Вот здесь тире стоит на месте.

```
А разве предложение "Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку"
не содержит однотипно построенных частей сложного предложения?
```

Да, можно сказать, что части построены однотипно: последовательность членов простых предложений одинаковая (с пропуском обстоятельства и сказуемого во втором). И здесь свою роль еще в большей степени играет интонация, обусловленная **смыслом** частей. Часто это просто перечисление, как в этом примере:

*Один встретил свою в лаборатории, другой — в радиорубке, третий — в геологической партии, четвёртый — в море, пятый — в небе, на скрещении воздушных дорог.*

А есть предложения, в которых помимо перечисления вступает в силу разнополярность частей:

*В зале говорили свидетели – торопливо, обесцвеченными голосами, судьи – неохотно и безучастно* (Горький); *Деньги – исчезают, работа – остаётся* (Горький); *Игра кончилась и наступило время для одних – радоваться выигрышу, для других – подсчитывать проигрыш.*

В этих примерах наблюдается четкое противопоставление ("конфликт") первой и второй частей сложного предложения. В случае с *Егорушкой* всего этого нет. Правила не перекрывают друг друга, а дополняют.

Answer (score 2):

***Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он Егорушку.***

Разве вот это предложение нельзя произнести с паузой перед словом "Егорушку"?

**Прекрасный вопрос думающего человека!** Потому что ответ на него будет такой – можно! Но автор выбрал вариант без тире, который, как он считал, подходит по контексту.

1) А теперь попробуем разобраться. Розенталь нередко упоминает интонацию и мелодику текста, но подробности не раскрывает. Поэтому мы вправе его спросить: « Пауза – это очень субъективная вещь, разве нет?»

Пауза – возможно, да и вся интонация представляется многим вещью субъективной и поэтому ненужной. Тему неполных предложений пользователи понимают с трудом, иногда интуитивно, но выход есть.

Мы не будем говорить об интонации вообще, а поговорим **об интонационной модели**. Всего два элемента составляют эту модель: **пауза и фраза.** Каждая фраза – это часть предложения, объединенная одним **тоническим (фразовым) ударением**. Обычно тоническое ударение делается в конце фразы (нейтральная интонация), если оно переносится на другое слово, то ударение становится **логическим.**

***Егорушка долго оглядывал егО, // а он ЕгОрушку.*** Две фразы, разделенные паузой, ударение падает на конец фразы (нейтральный вариант), при этом ударением выделены нужные нам предметы.

А попробуем так: ***Егорушка дОлго оглядывал его, а Он – ЕгОрушку.***

В первой фразе ударением подчеркнуто нужное слово (наречие ***долго***), но теперь вторую фразу с прежним ударением произнести не получается. Вот и приходится делить эту фразу на две части, ставить ударение и на местоимении ***он*** тоже, а после ударного слова делается обязательная пауза (иначе не произнесешь).

2) Также рассмотрим предложение, которое предлагает нам Александр в своем ответе: ***Егорушка долго оглядывал его, а он — бричку.***

Конечно, два варианта произношения возможны и здесь, но вариант без паузы кажется **нелогичным по семантике** (под ударную позицию попадают предметы несопоставимые).

Поэтому выбираем другую схему: ***Егорушка долго оглядывал егО, а Он — брИчку.*** В этом случае автор подчеркивает, что мальчики смотрят по-разному.
У Александра это объясняется так: в предложении появляется что-то **третье**. Что ж, похоже, все **три предмета выделены ударением.**

Так выглядит интонационный анализ. Научиться ему несложно, хотя надо немного постараться, но зато он вас никогда не подведет. Всё это проверяется в устной речи. Можно найти предложения с вариантами, иногда верен один вариант. Интонационный анализ будет для вас **универсальным инструментом,** с помощью которого вы без особого труда объясните решение многих задач.

3) Посмотрим еще пару **однотипно построенных примеров**. Там нет ничего нового: расставляем ударение и определяем наличие пауз.

*ДЕньги – исчезАют, рабОта – остаЁтся* (Горький); Это параллельная интонация, выделены и предметы, и действия.

*Деньги исчезАют, работа остаЁтся.* В этом варианте выделены только действия.

*Игра кончилась, и наступило время (какое?) для однИх – радоваться вЫигрышу, для другИх – подсчитывать прОигрыш.*

Однозначный вариант для сложного предложения. Мы не можем без паузы, в одну фразу, прочитать распространенные словосочетания, к тому же связанные перечислительной интонацией.

**Примечание.** В неполных предложениях используется разделительное тире с **повышением** голоса перед паузой. Этим оно отличается от **присоединительного** тире с **понижением** голоса перед паузой (как в конце предложения).

Comment: Спасибо. Даю свой голос.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно коротенький отзыв (всё ли понятно, с чем не согласны)? Читателей у меня немого, может быть, вы будете единственным.

Comment: Как немного? Может, и немного, но, мне кажется, все активные участники читают. Отзыв положительный: всё логично и понятно, интонация рулит! Несогласия нет. Я сначала тоже хотел написать, как и вы, что раз правило не запрещает, то можно ставить тире, но не стал, засомневавшись, согласится ли со мной Чехов. Я прочитал много ваших ответов — все они заставляют думать и что-то понять, и этот не исключение.

Comment: А о количестве читателей мы же не можем знать. Я, например, по запросу непонятных мне тем часто заходил сюда раньше, до того как решил окунуться.