# Знаки препинания расставлены правильно?

Tags: пунктуация

> В произведении “Отцы и дети” И.С. Тургенева мы видим настоящий
>   конфликт поколений: “отцов” - Павла Петровича, Николая Петровича
>   Керсановых - и “детей”: Евгения Базарова и Аркадия Кирсанова.

Comment: На ГИА именно такое предложение должно быть? Или его можно переделывать, разбивать на два, например?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если выразить мысль не одним предложением, а двумя-тремя, то можно [**так**](https://bingoschool.ru/blog/236/):

*В произведении “Отцы и дети” И. С. Тургенева мы видим самый настоящий конфликт поколений. К поколению «отцов» можно отнести Павла Петровича и Николая Петровича Кирсановых. Поколение «детей» – это Евгений Базаров и Аркадий Кирсанов.*

Тавтологии здесь нет.

Или [**так**](https://ctege.info/napravlenie-ottsyi-i-deti/argumentyi-po-napravleniyu-ottsyi-i-deti.html):

*В произведении "Отцы и дети" А. С. Тургенева ярко продемонстрирована проблема взаимоотношений двух поколений. «Отцы» – братья Николай и Павел Кирсановы, «дети» – Аркадий Кирсанов, сын Николая Петровича Кирсанова, и Евгений Базаров, друг Аркадия.*

Скопления двоеточий и тире в одном предложении лучше избегать. Проблему решают точки.

Comment: Спасибо. У меня кстати есть один интересный вопросик про тире. Не поможете? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/460573/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf

Answer (score 2):

Лучше написать, к примеру, так:

*В произведении “Отцы и дети” И.С. Тургенева мы видим реальный конфликт поколений: Павла Петровича и Николая Петровича Кирсановых (отцы) и Евгения Базарова и Аркадия Кирсанова (дети).*

В вашем предложении избыток "сильных" знаков препинания (двоеточие и тире), что плохо смотрится и так же плохо читается и понимается.

Comment: я боюсь, что на ГИА эти слова в скобках будут лишними, по другому никак? И почему перед второй "и" нет запятой?

Comment: Запятых нет, потому что союзы И не являются повторяющимися, они поставлены на разных основаниях. Если скобки не нравятся, то лучше вторую часть оформить как отдельное предложение, например: «Отцы» – это Николай Петрович  и Павел Петрович Кирсановы, а «дети» —  Аркадий Кирсанов, сын Николая Петровича, и его друг Евгений Базаров.